# How does Samsung remotely control Samsung model phones?

Tags: samsung

Only 2 days after purchasing one, I discovered Samsung has excercised its ability to remotely brick Samsung devices for any reason they choose.  (This came to attention after discovering [Samsung started bricking greymarket phones in Mexico](https://www.gearrice.com/update/samsung-begins-to-block-mobile-phones-purchased-on-the-gray-market-in-mexico-if-you-have-one-it-will-become-a-paperweight/))

I have unlocked the bootloader of the phone (and used Magisk to root it) and I did not sign up to Google or Samsung on the phone - but I'm wondering this is baked into their firmware - and if so how I can remove it.  (I'm not an expert, but I've hacked around with modifying android a bit in the past)

If it makes a difference the phone in question is a Galaxy A24 and I'm unaware of any custom ROMS for it.

Comment: This is the first time I heard about it, and I can't find any further research about how it works either. But if by "firmware" you mean "official ROM (+Samsung system apps)", then probably something, somewhere is related. Also, some discussion on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/samsung/comments/16pgliq/samsung_blocking_importedinternational_phones_in/), talking about NOM certification, CSC, and custom ROM (no confirmation)